# bound for the number of simple paths between $s$ and $t$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ a directed graph such that $|V|=n$, i.e. with $n$ vertices, and let $s,t\in V$ be some vertices. Give an upper bound for the number of simple paths between $s$ and $t$.

Comment: What do you think is a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clearly it is bounded by the number of paths in the complete graph.

How many are there?

They are the same as the number of sequences of non-repeating terms from the set $V\setminus\{s,t\}$ (counting the empty sequence)

The number of such paths is:

$(n-2)!+\frac{(n-2)!}{1!}+\frac{(n-2)!}{2!}+\dots+\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-2)!}=(n-2)!(1+1+\frac{1}{2!}+\dots+\frac{1}{(n-2)!})= $

$\lfloor (n-2)!e \rfloor$ (for $n\geq 4$)

Hence the best bound is exactly $\lfloor (n-2)!e\rfloor$